# How to create Expandable View for Product Details in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expandablelistview

I'm having problem on creating an expandable view for the product details. Can anyone help me out on how to create an expandable view like the picture attached. I want like if a user clicks the product details container, it will show product details. Pls help me out as im quite new to react native.

[image: Before pressed]

[image: Expandable View Image].

Comment: I see that there is no part of the expandable view before pressed, so can we say it's hidden or height: 0 initially?

Comment: its hidden actually

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, create ExpandableView component that requires `expanded` prop. The prop itself should be set/updated in parent component (`isExpanded`). Add effect dependency to this `expanded` prop in ExpandableView to run the animation. Notice that every time `isExpanded`'s value is changed, it rerenders ExpandableView component. Make sure rerendering happens only when needed, or you'll have performance issue.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Animated,
  Text,
} from "react-native";

const ExpandableView = ({ expanded = false }) => {
  const [height] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(height, {
      toValue: !expanded ? 200 : 0,
      duration: 150,
      useNativeDriver: false
    }).start();
  }, [expanded, height]);

  // console.log('rerendered');

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={{ height, backgroundColor: "orange" }}
    ></Animated.View>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          setIsExpanded(!isExpanded);
        }}
        style={styles.toggle}
      >
        <Text style={styles.toggleText}>Expand</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <ExpandableView expanded={isExpanded} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {},
  toggle: {
    width: 100,
    height: 30,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  toggleText: {
    color: "#fff"
  }
});

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/expandableview-qpkznz

[image]